# UISplitViewController - Wrong detail view sizing

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, detailview

I’m maintaining a universal iOS App whose development has started on iOS 6. I’m about the renew the UI for iOS 7. Now I’ve got a weird problem with the iPad part of the app. This part follows the „normal“ Master-Detail view pattern using a UISplitViewController. The UI is configured in a storyboard. The UISplitViewController is the root view controller as requested by Apples docs. 
Here comes the weird part: When the detail view controller is embedded in a UINavigationController the navigation controller will be sized incorrectly by the UISplitViewController and so the whole interface looks broken. It appears as if the navigation controller remains in portrait orientation even if the device orientation is landscape. In portrait orientation the detail view controller is looking fine though.
If I avoid embedding the detail view controller in a navigation controller and connect it directly as detail view controller with the UISplitViewController everything is working perfectly in both orientations. 
I tried to reproduce the problem in a simple sample App based on the Master-Detail project template provided by Apple without luck. There it works even with a detail view controller embedded in a navigation controller. No matter what I’ve tried so far (looking for categories interfering, rotation settings, method swizzling etc. pp.) I couldn’t find the cause for this problem. As I’m running out of options (if possible I’d rather avoid rolling my container view controller) I respectfully ask if anybody around here has a solution to this problem or further ideas on how to track down the problem.

Thanks in advance
Tino

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution to my own problem. I created a category on UISplitViewController and added a method 'detailViewController' only meant to be a convenience method to access the detail view. Unfortunately the UISplitViewController has an equally named internal method which is was replacing. Would I have followed Apples guidelines to always prefix category methods in order to avoid name clashes I would have saved a lot of my own time. :(

Comment: Thank god I found you posted this. Saved me a ton of time as well. I wish a NSLog would notify you if a crucial method like this was being overwritten on accident - but I guess prefixing is the best solution for now.